# How to insert data from one server into another server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure which is used to insert data from one server database table into another.

For this, I have two parameters `@server='ServerName'` and `@Database='DbName'`. And the table name is fixed.

I'm trying this like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Demo
    (@server NVARCHAR(100), @Database NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    SET @str = 'INSERT INTO ['+@server+'].' + @Database + '.DBO.TableName1 (Id, FirstName, LastName, Gender)
                    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Gender 
                    FROM TableName2'

    EXEC sp_executesql @str
END
```

This is working perfectly for same server but for another server giving below error:

> Msg 1206, Level 18, State 118, Procedure Demo, Line 74
>   The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction.

Server is linked server and table in both databases server is same. How to correct this script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you run: "BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION
SELECT * FROM <linkedServer>.<DatabaseName>.dbo.TableName2
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION"

Comment: Oh gods, that's wide open to injection! **NEVER** pass unsanitised strings into your dynamic statements. Use `QUOTENAME` to **safely** quote the object names. What do you suppose would happen if someone wrote the following? `CREATE TABLE T (I int);

EXEC demo @Server = N'T] VALUES(1); CREATE LOGIN SU WITH PASSWORD = ''123'', CHECK_POLICY = OFF, CHECK_EXPIRY = OFF; /*', @Database = N'*/ ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER SU; DROP TABLE T;--';`